# Write Higher Order Arrow Functions

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions

I'm doing FreeCodeCamp tasks, and now I get stuck with Arrow Function
Problem is : I need to sort an array(which "filter" function doing well - it sorts) but my map. function doesnt work. I get an error "((num > 0) && Number.isInteger(...)).map is not a function"

Thanks in advance

```
const realNumberArray = [4, 5.6, -9.8, 3.14, 42, 6, 8.34, -2];
const squareList = (arr) => {
  "use strict";
  const squaredIntegers = arr.filter((num) =>
   (num > 0 && Number.isInteger(num)).map((num) => Math.pow(num,2) )) 
  return squaredIntegers;
};
```

It should return an array the square of only the positive integers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the `.map` *after* the `.filter` is completely done:

```js
const realNumberArray = [4, 5.6, -9.8, 3.14, 42, 6, 8.34, -2];
const squareList = (arr) => {
  return arr
    .filter(num => num > 0 && Number.isInteger(num))
    .map(num => num ** 2)
};

console.log(squareList(realNumberArray));
```

Comment: The thing is : I have to use another "const  squaredIntegers "

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. If that makes this solution not workable for you for some reason, please edit your question so we all can see the full context of the problem.

Comment: Ok, This is the task: Use arrow function syntax to compute the square of only the positive integers (decimal numbers are not integers) in the array realNumberArrayand store the new array in the variable squaredIntegers

Comment: Sounds like you just need to assign the call of the function to that variable name? `const squaredIntegers = squareList(realNumberArray);`

Answer (score 1):

You can do everything together without using `return` or setting to another const:

```
const realNumberArray = [4, 5.6, -9.8, 3.14, 42, 6, 8.34, -2];

const squareList = (arr) => arr.filter(num => num > 0 && 
   Number.isInteger(num)).map(num => Math.pow(num,2));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using only reduce function.

```js
const list = [4, 5.6, -9.8, 3.14, 42, 6, 8.34, -2];
const result = list.reduce((acc, val) => {
  if (Number.isInteger(val) && val > 0) {acc.push(val*val)};
  return acc;
}, []);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

But you said *higher-order arrow functions* ^_^

```js
const squareList = arr =>
  $ (arr)                        // beginning with arr,
    (filter (num => num > 0))    // filter
    (filter (Number.isInteger))  // filter some more
    (map (x => x ** 2))          // map
    ($)                          // extract result

const map = f => xs =>
  xs .map (x => f (x))           // Array.prototype.map
  
const filter = f => xs =>
  xs .filter (x => f (x))        // Array.prototype.filter

const $ = x =>      // beginning with x,
  f =>              // and a function, f,
    f === $         // exit condition
      ? x           // return x
      : $ (f (x))   // otherwise, transform x using f and recur

const realNumbers =
  [ 4, 5.6, -9.8, 3.14, 42, 6, 8.34, -2 ]
  
const result =
  squareList (realNumbers)

console.log(result)
// [ 16, 1764, 36 ]
```

Functions like `$` allow us to think about our problem in different ways. Above we see `squareList` take an array and pass it down the "pipe" vertically. Intuitively, it's nice to think about the problem as sequence of `arr->filter->filter->map` but this is a wasteful computation. As others have pointed out, it can be done with a single `reduce`. Wouldn't it be nice if we could have our cake and eat it too?

Functional programming is all about programming with functions. This doesn't mean we have to forfeit writing programs in a particular way. Simply write functions to isolate complexity and do the hard work for you.

Below, `squareList` is exactly the same as above, but this time we change the program's behaviour dramatically by refactoring `$`. Instead of running `filter->filter->map` in sequence, this version builds up a pending computation and runs a single `reduce` when the value is popped out. A popular name for this technique is *transducers*; here I've encoded them using arrow functions.

Higher-order arrow functions for days ^_^

```js
const squareList = arr =>
  $ (arr)                       // beginning with arr,
    (filter (num => num > 0))   // add filter transducer
    (filter (Number.isInteger)) // add another filter transducer
    (map (x => x ** 2))         // add map transducer
    ($)                         // run transducer

const map = f =>                   // map transducer
  k => (r, x) => k (r, f (x))
  
const filter = f =>                // filter transducer
  k => (r, x) => f (x) ? k (r, x) : r

const $ = (x, t = identity) =>     // beginning with x and base transducer,
  f =>                             // and a function, f,
    f === $                        // exit condition
      ? x .reduce (t (push), [])   // run transducer; single reduce
      : $ (x, comp (t, f))         // otherwise, recur with new transducer

const identity = x =>
  x

const push = (r, x) =>
  ( r .push (x)
  , r
  )

const comp = (f, g) =>
  x => f (g (x))

const realNumbers =
  [ 4, 5.6, -9.8, 3.14, 42, 6, 8.34, -2 ]
  
const result =
  squareList (realNumbers)

console.log(result)
// [ 16, 1764, 36 ]
```

Above `$` only iterates over the input array *once*, compared to `filter->filter->map` which iterates over the input array *three* (3) times. This is a big performance gain in scenarios where `arr` is significantly large.

`$` could be *anything* – and because it's a function, it gives us a domain we can control and make meaningful changes; maybe we make some performance optimisations; maybe it could throw a `TypeError` if an invalid argument is given; maybe we call it `pipe` or call it `trans` or whatever. Don't get stuck thinking functional programming begins and ends at `Array.prototype.map`, `Array.prototype.filter`, `Array.prototype.reduce` et al. *You* imagine the magic wand and *you* create it ^_^

Answer (score 0):

```
const realNumberArray = [4,5.6,-9.8,3.14,42,6,8.34,-2];
const squareList = (arr) => {
    const squaredIntegers = arr.filter(num => typeof num ==="number" && 
    isFinite(num) && Math.floor(num) === num && num>0).map(num => num ** 2)
    return squaredIntegers;
};
const squaredIntegers = squareList(realNumberArray);
console.log(squaredIntegers);
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, including an explanation of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply